# I cannot install numpy or pandas using pip

Tags: python, numpy

I cannot install numpy, so everytime that I try to run my model shows:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 Complete output (200 lines):
    Running from numpy source directory.
    setup.py:470: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
```

Any idea how to get it fixed?

Comment: which version of Python? paste the full error here.

Comment: what were your command and the complete error log?